# How do I remove an extra square bracket from JSON in Python?

Tags: python, json

I have JSON of the following form:

```
{"blah":
 [
   [
     {"first":
     {"something":"that","something":"else","another":"thing","key":"value"}...[etc.]
     }
   ]
 ]
}
```

that I'm trying to parse in Python. I've imported json (or simplejson, depending on what version of Python you're using) and everything goes pretty well until I get to this block:

```
for result in page['blah']:
  that = result['first']
  a_list.append(that)
```

which throws the error "TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str".

I'm pretty sure this error is due to the extra pair of square-bracket that makes the JSON inside look like a list.

My question, assuming that's the case, is, How do I remove it and still have valid JSON to parse as dictionaries?

Other workarounds welcome. If I need to supply more info, let me know. Thanks!

(Added the missing curly bracket and changed a couple of confusing terms--I was trying to come up with generic terms on the fly, sorry for any confusion.)

Comment: You seem to be missing a curly bracket.

Comment: Can you post the complete code, because as Zhehao Mao said, you seem to be missing a comment, and it's hard to tell if your problem comes from this or from something else...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there's always exactly one "extra" set of array brackets:

```
for result in page['blah']:
    that = result[0]['this']
    list.append(that)
```

Comment: Felix's answer correctly points out that the sample structure doesn't quite match up with your code sample. If you really do want an "inner" value of the JSON object, and not the whole object that's within the outermost curly brackets, then you'll need to do something like that.

Answer (score 0):

There is not need to remove the brackets from the JSON string. I think making sure to remove only the rights is not worth the effort. Just figure out the right way to access the values you want.

The "extra" brackets are not the only problem. `this` is a property of an object which is the value of `first`. So to access `this`, you'd have to write

```
that = result[0]['first']['this']
```

Whether this always works or not depends on the left-out JSON data.

Comment: Ah, sorry, I was coming up with generic words on the fly. You're absolutely right, and rest assured that I'm using neither "this" nor "list" in the actual code.

Answer (score 0):

First, you are right - your error is related to the incorrect use of the Python data types and JSON output.

Second, don't use `list` and all other Python reserved words when creating your variables.

Finally, if you simply want to get all results for *'this'* inner key, you can try using the following code:

```
data = {"blah":
 [
   [
     {"first":
     {"this":"that",
     "something":"else","another":"thing","key":"value"}}
   ]
 ]
}
outres = []
for k,v in data.items():#iterate over top dictionary('blah',....)
    for sv in v: # iterate through first list
        for tv in sv: # iterate through second list
            for fk,fv in tv.iteritems(): # iterate through each dicionary from second list
                if 'this' in fv:
                    outres.append(fv['this'])
print outres
```

Please note that my sample is based on your data sample - so if there is any additional levels in your data structure, or if any other rules should be applied, then the code should be modified.